# MySQL 600-700% CPU after upgrade from 5.7 to 8.0.13

Tags: mysql

[htop picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSr2R.jpg)

I have 0 slow queries in the log, tried with different my.cnf configurations. Can't see what's the problem. 8 cpu server, 32GB ram, ssd, dedicated mysql server. All cpus > 100%, it's starts slowly, works perfect in the first 15-30 minutes then it goes crazy. High load without reason.

After upgrade i did mysql_upgrade and everything looked ok. Now running 8.0.13 and almost all my tables are MyISAM

`[my.cnf] 
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
sql-mode=""
character-set-server=utf8
default-storage-engine         = MyISAM
wait-timeout=300
long_query_time = 1
slow-query-log                 = 1
slow-query-log-file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long-query-time = 1
skip_name_resolve = 1
general_log = 0
query_prealloc_size=32K  # from default to avoid RAM acquisition all day
query_alloc_block_size=32K  # from default to manage larger blocks
innodb_buffer_pool_size=10G  # from 128M to reduce innodb_buffer_pool_reads
innodb_lru_scan_depth=128  # from 1024 per REFMAN when ibp_instances=8
expire_logs_days=5  # from 0 for limited historical error,general,slow logs
slow_query_log=ON  # from OFF to allow awareness of ~ 2000 in 76 days, for improvement of queries
thread_cache_size=100  # from 12 to reduce threads_created 353K
max_connections=200  # from 400 for max_used_connections 56 x ~ 4
innodb_io_capacity=1000  # from 200 to open the door wider
innodb_change_buffer_max_size=10  # from 25% to reduce set aside for CHGS, etc
max_write_lock_count=16  # from HUGE number to allow RD after nn lcks
join_buffer_size=128M  # from 4096 for join capacity increase
sort_buffer_size=2M  # from 256K to reduce sort_merge_passes ~ 1m
updatable_views_with_limit=NO  # from YES to reduce handler_external_lock cnt
open_files_limit = 32000
table_open_cache = 2000
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
key-buffer-size=64M`

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%'
bulk_insert_buffer_size 8388608 
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size   134217728

innodb_buffer_pool_dump_at_shutdown ON

innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_dump_pct 25

innodb_buffer_pool_filename ib_buffer_pool

innodb_buffer_pool_instances    8

innodb_buffer_pool_load_abort   OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_load_at_startup  ON

innodb_buffer_pool_load_now OFF 
innodb_buffer_pool_size 10737418240 
innodb_change_buffer_max_size   10

innodb_change_buffering all 
innodb_log_buffer_size  16777216

innodb_sort_buffer_size 1048576 
join_buffer_size    134217728

key_buffer_size 67108864

myisam_sort_buffer_size 8388608 
net_buffer_length   16384

preload_buffer_size 32768

read_buffer_size    131072

read_rnd_buffer_size    2097152 
sort_buffer_size    2097152 
sql_buffer_result   OFF`

Comment: What did you see in `innotop`?

Comment: Nothing serious https://i.imgur.com/6Y9Al4il.jpg

Comment: also htop https://i.imgur.com/CgEuxWV.jpg

Comment: Look at the rest of the data in innotop. You should be able to find something useful.

Comment: Solved the issue. Did a dump, installed a fresh mysql 8.0 and then imported. Everything is perfect now. Thank you very much !

Comment: @maxshop - Connect as root and do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`.  This might give you a quick clue of the several processes that are battling for CPU, etc.@maxshop

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
key_cache_age_threshold=7200  # from 300 seconds to reduce key_reads
```

since most of your tables are MyISAM to improve performance of your instance.